# ansible: copy run scp - just goes on and on never ends

Tags: ansible

I have below task to copy running config to remote server.

```
- name: Copying confg to remote server
  cisco.nxos.nxos_command:
    commands:
    - command: copy run scp://{{ username }}@{{ remote_server }}{{ remote_location }}/{{ hostname }}_config.txt vrf management
      prompt:
      - "password:"
      answer:
      - "{{ password }}"
```

I did debug using -vvv. This approach just goes on and on never ends.

```
> <192.168.1.1> ANSIBLE_NETWORK_IMPORT_MODULES: found cisco.nxos.nxos_command  at /usr/local/Cellar/ansible/6.5.0/libexec/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ansible_collections/cisco/nxos/plugins/modules/nxos_command.py
> <192.168.1.1> ANSIBLE_NETWORK_IMPORT_MODULES: running cisco.nxos.nxos_command
```

how to fix it? I was looking at cisco.nxos.nxos_file_copy module but it is to copy file from remote server to nexus device. I need to copy file from nexus device to remote server so I can't use it.

Comment: Have you tried to use the `cisco.nxos.nxos_config` module to setup that file? https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/cisco/nxos/nxos_config_module.html

Comment: it backup file locally on ansible folder. I want to backup running config to remote scp server.

Comment: The most probable cause for a command task hanging for ever in Ansible is a prompt waiting for an answer that is not given. Either your prompt/answer config does not match reality or there's an other prompt before/after password.

Comment: yes. that correct. ansible is waiting for prompt "password:" on host but scp server is sending "Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?" to host. how to have host device ignore ssh key authentication checking with scp server?

Answer (score 0):

The scp command syntax looks a little wrong to me. Seems to be missing `:` after {{ remote_server }}

Example: scp username@server:filepath /local/directory/